# Why would this be giving a 500 error for such a simple rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying to do some very simple page redirection on a shared server that I have very limited access to (no control panel, no error or server logs etc). I've stripped it right back but for some reason i'm still getting a 500 error even with just the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact /contact.php [NC]
```

When visiting www.domain.com/contact you get a 500 error. I have sent a message to support but they're not very helpful (i'm trying to get the error logs) and it's around Christmas so they'll probably be very slow. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be failing on a shared server as I can't work out why. I don't think they've blocked htaccess use as I have tried setting 404 redirects and preventing access to certain file types via htaccess and both of these work fine.

Thanks so much,

Dave

Comment: Is there a server error on the page itself. Does www.domain.com/contact.php work? Just asking

Comment: Yes it works :) FYI i just edited the question slighly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a loop with this, because `^contact` also matches `contact.php`.

Try somethin like this:

```
^contact$
```

Comment: Ah yes, what a complete muppet, sorry :) Thanks for pointing that out!